# Showing $(M^\perp)^\perp=\overline{M}$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

I have a question about a step in proving $(M^\perp)^\perp=\overline{M}$ where $M$ is a linear subspace of a normed vector space $E$. And $M^\perp=\{f\in E^*|\langle f,x\rangle =0\}$

This is the proof from Brezis book:

Proof: Assuming the other direction, show $\subset$ direction. Suppose there exists $x_0\in (M^\perp)^{\perp}$ such that $x_0\notin \overline{M}$. Then, Hahn-Banach says there exists a hyperplane that strictly separates $\{x_0\}$ and $\overline{M}$. Thus there are some $f\in E^*$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $$
\langle f,x\rangle <\alpha<\langle f, x_0\rangle, \forall x\in M$$

Since $M$ is a linear space it follows that $\langle f,x\rangle =0$(WHY??), for all $x$ and $\langle f, x_0\rangle >0$. Therefore $f\in M^\perp$ and consequently $\langle f, x_0\rangle =0$, a contradiction.

Can someone tell me why the place (WHY??) is true? I couldn't find out the line follows from the fact that $M$ is a linear space.

Thanks

Comment: Why $x_0\in E$?  Is it necessary  to add $E$ is a reflexive space?

Answer (score 2):

Pick $\beta \in \mathbb R$ then 
$$\beta \langle f, x\rangle=\langle f, \beta x\rangle  < \alpha $$

Since this happens for all $\beta \in \mathbb R$, it follows that $\langle f,x\rangle=0$.

Comment: wow, that was simple. Actually was it was used in previous steps. Thanks. Also, the definition of $M^\perp$ is equvalent with the regular definition of $M^\perp=\{x\in E, (x,y)=0, y\in M\}$?

Comment: How to prove the other direction $\supset$?

Comment: @soundwave If $x \in \overline{M}$ then you can find some $x_n \in M$ such that $x_n \to x$... Then, for each $f \in M^\perp$ you have $$<f,x> = \lim_n <f, x_n> = \lim_n 0=0$$

Comment: @N.S. Thank you very much!

Comment: @N.S. I'm trying to understand why from $\beta \langle f, x\rangle=\langle f, \beta x\rangle  < \alpha, \ \forall\ \beta\in\mathbb{R}$, it follows that $\langle f,x\rangle=0$. If $\alpha<0$ the inequality does not hold anymore, does it?

Comment: @soundwave If $<f,x> \neq 0$ then it is either negative or positive. If $< f,x> >0$ then pick $\beta > \frac{\alpha}{<f,x> }$. If $< f,x> < 0$ then pick $\beta < \frac{\alpha}{<f,x> }$.

Comment: @soundwave To make this a bot more clear, if $<f,x> \neq 0$ then $\beta <f,x>$ goes to $+ \infty$ at one of $\pm \infty$, depending on the sign of $<f,x>$. Therefore it cannot be bounded.

Comment: @soundwave And your argument explains why we must also have $\alpha >0$ in this case... Note that the hyperplane separating these points means that the inequalities could actually be opposite way, so this part should be WLOG :)

Comment: @N.S. Thank you for all the explanations, but I'm still struggling with this :( Doesn't $\langle f,x \rangle >0$ imply $\beta<\frac{\alpha}{\langle f,x\rangle }$ and $\langle f,x\rangle  < 0$ imply $\beta > \frac{\alpha}{\langle f,x\rangle  }$? I think this because if we have $-3a<b$ and we divide by $-3$, then the sign changes direction, ie $a>\frac{b}{-3}$. Isn't it?

Comment: Moreover, what does it mean that $\beta \langle f,x\rangle$ goes to $+\infty$ at one of $\pm\infty$ depending on the sign of the inner product?

Comment: @soundwave Exactly. $<f,x> >0$ implies some restriction on $\beta$... But you can pick $\beta$ anything you want.... Therefore, picking $\beta$ to cpntradict the restriction you get a ..... contradiction.

Comment: Ah thanks maybe a got it. So, recapping, by Hahn-Banach there are some functions $f$ in the big space $E$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\langle f,x\rangle <\alpha,\ \forall x\in M (*)$. The condition $(*)$ is equivalent to $\langle f, \beta x\rangle  < \alpha,\ \forall\ \beta \in \mathbb R$, for a fixed $x$ since $M$ is a linear space. But by taking those values of $\beta$ we talked before, we get a contradiction (there are some $\beta$ for which the relation $(*)$ doesn't hold). So the only way for $(*)$ to hold is to have $\langle f,x \rangle = 0$. Is this correct?

Comment: @soundwave Yes... If you want to be more precise, if you assume by contradiction that $\langle f,x \rangle \neq  0$ you can find a value of $\beta$ which contradicts $\langle f, \beta x\rangle  < \alpha$.

Comment: @N.S. ah good thank you very much. Lastly, to apply Hahn-Banach we have to be sure that $\overline M$ and $(M^{\perp})^\perp$ are closed and convex? I know that $\overline M$ is closed because the closure is closed by definition, and also $(M^{\perp})^\perp$ is closed since the orthogonal complement is always closed. About convex?

Comment: @soundwave They are both subspaces.